Piano fingering for seemingly impossible chord in RH
I'm trying to find a way to finger this chord in a manner other than that marked by the editor, where a thumb that covers two black keys separated by two white keys (assuming that's what's intended here with the marked fingering) seems impossible. Any advice would be much appreciated. 

Just to understand your question/problem: why do want/need an alternative to the suggested fingering?

Because I can't play it as marked. I've had to skip the A-sharp.

If you can't reach from A# to C# then I agree it's impossible, and dropping the bottom A# is reasonable. Should be quite a fast tempo, so an arpeggio is probably not such a good idea, and would anyway be quite tricky. FWIW, I can span from A# to C# and can use the fingering as written quite easily, even though the hand ends up in a strange shape.

I guess the editor has long thumbs.

@robchop for future reference always include the composer and title, eventually edition and year of publication. This piece was easily recognizable, still we shouldn't be making efforts in "guessing" a piece.

Alternatively take the lower A♯ into left hand one octave lower, playing F♯-A♯-C♯-E instead. Simply leaving out the lower A♯ is also possible, but will result in a less dense chord.

Also you could very well play the right hand as arpeggio.

@musicamante Thanks. My apologies. I will do that from now on.

It, of course, is Chopin's Prelude in A major, Op. 28, No. 7. (Peters edition, 2004.)

@Lazy Excellent idea. Didn't think of that. And that new five-fingered chord in the LH is a bit easier to play than that in the RH. Thank you.

The whole chord is tricky, but the A# and C# with the thumb shouldn't be. I have small hands (1 octave hard limit) and the C# hits the base of the thumb comfortably. If I can do it and Chopin can do it, anyone in between can.

@BrianChandler The piece is not especially fast, and it's common to slow slightly when approaching this chord.

@Aaron. Sorry. If I had found that post in my -- albeit brief -- initial search, I certainly would not have posted this question.

Appreciate all the great feedback on this. My right hand has now adapted a bit to playing this and is somewhat able to make the chord, but it’s not a clean strike (bit of a splat with the thumb hitting the two black (A♯, C♯) and two white (B,C) keys altogether, although the white keys are not fully depressed). Will keep working on it. Have tried the other options and all are possible, with one thus far preferable. My apologies also for this somewhat redundant post (see "What is the best way to play a chord larger than your hand?"), as indicated by Aaron.

True, it's a handful! I can just span an octave, so for me too, it's impossible as written. Two ways round - since it's pedalled, play as a quasi arpeggio, getting the lower A♯ in, and sliding to the right for the rest of the notes. Or, leave out that particular A♯, as there is another an octave higher, which most ears will detect better anyway.
Maybe it was written by someone with a large handspan? Who, and what piece?

@robchop Leaving out notes is not a "mortal sin". You should obviously try to play everything, but sometimes you just can't, others nobody would care (or is even able to listen). Note that there's absolutely nothing wrong with using the thumb for black keys, nor with playing two keys with one finger. Whomever says the opposite is just following archaic rules that made no sense (except for their arrogant presumption) even when they were "established". There's only one rule for fingering that can be considered as "absolute": it has to make sense in order to be able to accurately play the piece.

@robchop Don't make the A# the bottom of a RH arpeggio; make it the top of a LH arpeggio. Much easier.

This is the seventh of the Chopin Preludes, Op.28.
Some editions add an arpeggio line for the left hand, hinting that the chord is not expected to be played all at once.
Note that it is quite common to use arpeggio even when not explicitly written, both as a stylistic choice and for practical reasons.
For some styles and instruments it's actually considered part of the common performance practice: for instance, in classical guitar, or when playing open chords on string instruments (eg. Bach's Chaconne). It doesn't have to be explicitly written.
Listening to various renditions, we can find various interpretations of that chord, with some playing all notes at the same time, others with different "styles" of arpeggio.
Interestingly enough, Yuja Wang clearly just plays the lower F alone and then moves the left for the remaining notes, most certainly in order to play the lower A of the right hand with the left hand instead.
This is actually a common way of playing some "extended chords", especially important ones: at the maximum tension of a cadence (like in this case) or at its resolution.
See the following performance (the chord is right after the 9th minute):



Still, it's not impossible to play it.
It obviously is more difficult for beginners and people with smaller hands, but with some accurate practice (aka: don't push it too hard, be patient), it can be done even as written by most people.

Another way, if you can play a tenth with your left hand, which isn't uncommon, is to drop the F#4 (assuming '4' to be the 'middle' octave) and move A#4 to the left hand, thus:



Note that per Lazy's suggestion, I'm doing F♯-A♯-C♯-E in the LH instead of F♯-C♯-E-A♯, thus avoiding another long stretch (i.e., a 10th). (Unless we're talking the A♯ as the top of an LH arpeggio, as Aaron suggests.)

I beg to differ. Lazy wrote Alternatively take the lower A♯ into left hand one octave lower, whereas I don't suggest you shift A# an octave lower, in fact it will have a totally different impression (worse IMO, because notes in the bass have to be spaced to sound good). Also, hands change as you practice pieces, they literally stretch. Fingering that seemed impossible at first sometimes feels like the only sensible one after a few months of practice, so give the original, editor's fingering a try.

Also, I checked with Ekier's National Edition (the one suggested by the Int'l Chopin Competition in Warsaw), and there's a variant written by Chopin himself into a pupil's copy of the prelude, which I'll include in my answer.

"I beg to differ." Right. That's why I wrote the follow-up to clarify. Thanks.

Thanks very much for posting that Chopin variant.
